# QGIS development version(2.99) and python api questions

Tags: qgis, python, pyqgis, python-3

Can I use QGIS 2.99 PyQGIS in standalone apps like the others QGIS version?

Do I need python 3.6 to use this python api?

Comment: Welcome to gis.stackexchange. Please not that the format of this Q&A site requires us to stick to one question per thread. Please edit your post to focus on one question only. Feel free to post any additional question in additional threads.

Comment: Please see [Why do QGIS 2.99 and 2.18 behave different when I use canvas.setDestinationCrs?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/q/236286/64785)

Comment: @Midavalo i need information about python api on QGIS 2.99 that post say about specific thing.thank you

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, you need Python 3.6 for QGIS 2.99. It should be installed automatically if all dependencies are resolved correctly.

[image]

Comment: i need standalone script the steps is some with others QGIS versions to create apps out of QGIS  ?

Comment: what you mean "automatically if all dependencies are resolved correctly'' ?